# Using modifier with _ConditionalContent view in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

This is probably a silly question but I can't seem to be able to find much info on this.

I was wondering why doing something like this would result in an error "Instance member 'padding' cannot be used on type 'View'":

```
if [some condition] {
  Text("Hello World")
} else {
  EmptyView()
}
.padding()
```

My understanding is that that if-else is turned into a _ConditionalContent<Text, EmptyView> which is a one type of View, so we should be able to append modifiers?

I know I could just do something like:

```
let ifContent: _ConditionalContent<Text, EmptyView> = ViewBuilder.buildEither(...
let elseContent: _ConditionalContent<Text, EmptyView> = ViewBuilder.buildEither(...
let view = someCondition ? ifContent : elseContent

return view.padding()
```

which would achieve the same effect?

Comment: In the second example you apply padding to a specific type that conforms to View but in the first example you apply it to some View. And a simpler solution would be to wrap the if/else in a Group imo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to apply a modifier to the `_ConditionalContent` view created by the if statement. However, an if statement is not an expression, so calling methods on it is not possible according to Swift's syntax. Swift parses the `.padding()` line as a standalone [implicit member expression](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/expressions/#Implicit-Member-Expression). Since the context (presumably a view builder) expects a `View`, `.padding()` is short for `View.padding()`, which obviously doesn't work.

To make the if statement a "view that you can call methods on", wrap it in a `Group`:

```
Group {
    if ... {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
.padding()
```

Unlike a `VStack`/`HStack` etc, a `Group` does not add any additional layout behaviour or anything like that. SwiftUI treats this as if the the `Group` never existed at all, and the modifiers you add to the group will be added to the `_ConditionalContent` inside the `Group`.

Comment: Thanks @Sweeper for the explanation. I'm aware that I could use a container like Group/VStack/Hstack to wrap the if-else. Guess I need to read up a bit more on function builder and expression.